# I have a functional way to read a directory and log the stats, how I can get all folders tree stats recursively in a functional way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming

I was able to make the code bellow which is only reading a directory and then logging a list of Stats.
Now I am wondering how I can traverse the directory tree and retrieve a list of objects with stats and file paths.

```
import fs from 'fs'
import {Task, traverse,concat,compose,chain,map, prop, List, filter } from './shared/functional.js';

// readDir :: String -> Task Error (List String)
const readDir = path => new Task((reject, result) => {
  fs.readdir(path, (err, data) => (err ? reject(err) : result(new List(data))));
});

// readDir :: String -> Task Error (Stat)
const readStat = filename => new Task((reject, result) => {
  fs.stat(filename, (err, data) => (err ? reject(err) : result(data)));
});

const dirList = dir => chain(traverse(Task.of, compose(readStat, concat(dir))), readDir(dir),);

dirList('./shared/').fork(console.error, map(compose(console.log, prop('mtimeMs'))));
```

I am guessing I would need to use isDirectory to check if I should get inner in the tree or not. But them my questions is how to construct the object and how to return a not nested List?

EDIT: I am not using any libraries right now just following the types and helpers from https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/

EDIT2: I came up with the following:

```
import fs from 'fs'
import {Task, traverse,concat,compose,chain,map, prop, List, filter, Maybe,identity,Either,curry } from './shared/functional.js';

// readDir :: String -> Task Error (List String)
const readDir = path => new Task((reject, result) => {
  fs.readdir(path, (err, data) => (err ? reject(err) : result(new List(data))));
});

// readDir :: String -> Task Error (Stat)
const readStat = filename => new Task((reject, result) => {
  fs.stat(filename, (err, data) => (err ? reject(err) : result(data)));
});

const isDir = curry((dir, stat) => {
  return stat.isDirectory()
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define
    ? dirListAll(dir)
    : stat;
});

const dirListAll = dir => chain(traverse(Task.of, compose(map(isDir(dir)),readStat, concat(dir))), readDir(dir),);
```

and now I have the scenario I explained, in this example I have a directory with 6 items in it being 2 folders. so I get a list with 4 stats and 2 tasks.

```
Task {fork: ƒ} 0 (6) [Task, Stats, Stats, Stats, Task, Stats]
```

The later that can have lists in it, what I need to now is remove the outer functors, I am trying with possibly with traverse chain again. but no success yet.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably noticed that callbacks and loops don't fit well together. To solve this problem, I recommend using `util.promisify`. Once you have done that you can easily write an async function like this:

```
async function traverse(names, callback) {
  for (let name of names) {
    let s = await stat(name);
    if (s.isDirectory())
      await traverse( (await readdir(name)).map(x => path.join(name, x)) , callback );
    else
      callback(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I already have a async (as many other on the internet) code that does that with Promises but they are not pure. 

It has to be functional. I need to able to compose the calls without actually firing them. As it is with Task in the code above. 

Task type works just like with promises but functional. So that is not what I am looking for. I will update the edit the title thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo I suppose you can make an async wrapper function and use that instead of promisify?

Comment: That is what Task is doing. The question is given the functionality I already have how I can get the tree stats without having Tasks within Lists.